# MacBook Pro 13 doesn't fall asleep when the lid closed

Tags: sleep-wake, power, macbook-pro

I have a late 2012 MacBook Pro 13'. I've faced a strange problem: my Macbook does NOT switch into sleep mode when the lid closed. Same when open the lid - it does not wake. Instead of closing/opening the lid I have to use the Power button. It seems to be a mechanical problem, cos I've reinstalled mac os and it was in vain. Guys from my local official apple service said, that there is probably a lid-open/close sensor failure. But all they supposed to do - buy the new motherboard. Bad idea=) So, maybe you do have some ideas about that? Have anyone faced the same problem? Or maybe you know something about this sensor?

Here's the result of `pmset -g`

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power -1*
AC Power -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay 4200
 standby 1
 halfdim 1
 sms 1
 hibernatefile /var/vm/sleepimage
 disksleep 10
 sleep 93
 autopoweroffdelay 14400
 hibernatemode 3
 autopoweroff 1
 ttyskeepawake 1
 displaysleep 15
 acwake 0
 lidwake 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with a test to find out your settings.

copy paste following in your Terminal

```
pmset -g
```

now copy paste results here

If you think it is the sensor (unlikely)

To test the sensor, take a small (SMALL) magnet like the one on your Fridge, and slowly slide it where the screen and keyboard connect. The sensor is usually at the outer most edge of the keyboard part, while the build in magnet (yes there is one already inside your Mac) is usually in the screen portion (outer edges)

Comment: Helpful tip, I have issued pmset commands before, however I was not aware of the command to output current settings.  Thanks!

Comment: Terminal says this:
Active Profiles:
Battery Power  -1*
AC Power  -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 disksleep            10
 sleep                93
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         15
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1

Comment: what is all about?

Comment: the last one is of interest here and it does say to wake when lid is opened. Lidwake 1

Comment: so it seems, that it is for real a mechanical problem?

Comment: to check for mechanical problem use the magnet test

Comment: no reaction when using magnet